# get R classes of rpy2 dataframe

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, rpy2

In R, I can do

```
> df <- read.csv("file.csv")
> sapply(df, class)
  patient      time    censor WHO.Grade       Age       Sex 
 "factor" "numeric" "integer"  "factor"  "factor"  "factor"
```

How can I get the equivalent output from rpy2?

I have tried a number of things, but what I really want is to fill in the blank:

```
>>> df = DataFrame.from_csvfile("file.csv")
>>> r.sapply(df, _____)
```

This doesn't give the output I want,

```
>>> df.rclass
<rpy2.rinterface.SexpVector - Python:0x100b2bd98 / R:0x7fbb0bed62d8>
```

Nor does:

```
>>> df.rx2("time").rclass
<rpy2.rinterface.SexpVector - Python:0x100b2ba68 / R:0x7fbb0bed42a8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
colclasses = [tuple(x.rclass) for x in df]
```